# Function call in templates or precalculate needed values?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor, ngxs, angular-changedetection

I read that function calls in templates are not very efficient since Angular's default change detection will execute that function every time. Are function calls okay if one uses the
`OnPush` strategy? I am using NGXS for state management and the concept of dumb/smart components/containers. Should I preprocess objects so that they have already the values needed? Here is an example:

```
<div *ngFor="let object of objects">
    <input type="checkbox" [checked]="isObjectChecked(object)">
</div>
```

```
isObjectChecked(object){
    // if object is in the array, then check the checkbox
    return selectedObjects.some(obj => obj.id === object.id)
}
```

Since I am using NGXS I pass `objects` from the container to the dumb component using `@Input()`. Is this approach better:

```
// in container 
ngOnInit(){
        this.objectsWithIsCheckedProperty$ =  combineLatest([this.store.select(ObjectsState.objects), this.store.select(ObjectsState.selectedObjects)])
        .pipe(
            map(data => {
                let objects = data[0];
                let selectedObjects = data[1];
                objects.forEach(obj => {
                    obj.isChecked = selectedObjects.some(object => obj.id === object.id);
                });
                return objects;
            })
        )
    }
```

and then use the `isChecked` value in the template

```
<div *ngFor="let object of objects">
    <input type="checkbox" [checked]="object.isChecked">
</div>
```

Would it make a difference if I use the `OnPush` change detection strategy with function calls in templates since I have to explicitly tell that Angular should check whether variables changed?

Comment: This is still a bad practice, since the functions will be run during the changeDetection cycle of that component (any input changes, any event triggered in the component that you listen on,...). The performance might be fine, depending on what you are going for, but I'd strongly recommend not building that habit.

Comment: @pascalpuetz Do you mean the first approach? So is the second approach fine? If not, which approach should I choose in general?

Comment: I meant using functions in your templates is a bad practice. I would recommend the second approach with a slight modification: Instead of mutating the object via `obj.isChecked = ...`, I'd create a new object using a combination of `map` and spread syntax: `objects.map(obj => ({ ...obj, isChecked: selectedObjects.some(({id}) => id === obj.id ) }))`. Alternatively, since you are using NGXS, I'd even more recommend doing all of that logic in a `@Selector` and use that Selector in your component. I guess I should make that an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: @pascalpuetz Thank you for the clarification. This was just an example. I would also implement the logic in ```@Selector``` but I cant use services in selectors and there are cases where the logic is too complex so that I outsource parts. Then I have to somehow apply the outsourced function and that is only possible by creating a new observable and combining needed data and then applying the logic as above

Comment: You're very welcome. I added this as an answer with a bit more description as well. And of course, there are cases where you don't want or can do everything in a Selector. Just didn't want to leave that unmentioned, since that's also a possible solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Alternative 1: Functions in the template**

I strongly recommend not using functions when binding to your template. Even if you use `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`, these functions will be reevaluated whenever a change detection cycle is triggered on your component (e.g. when any `@Input` changes, any event you're listending on is triggered on your component, asynchronous tasks on your component complete).

As an example, imagine you have the following Component:

```js
@Component({
  template: `
    <span>{{ myBoundFunc() }}</span>
    <button (click)="doSomething()"
  `
})
export class MyComponent {
  myBoundFunc() {
    console.log('Bound function called');
  }
  doSomething() {}
}
```

Now if you click the button, `myBoundFunc` will be called as well since clicking the button triggers a change detection cycle - the result of `myBoundFunc` might change due to your click after all.

This might be okay performance-wise in this example, but it is a bad practice and will lead to performance issues if you do something more demanding in that function.

**Alternative 2: Precalculate the value in your Observable**

This is a good solution, since your logic will only run when the underlying observable receives a new value. Performance-wise, this is miles better than alternative 1. I'd still recommend doing this in an immutable way, since this works better with Angular's change detection (which only checks for reference equality).

I'd change your example solution to something like this to make it immutable:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.objectsWithIsCheckedProperty$ = combineLatest([
    this.store.select(ObjectsState.objects),
    this.store.select(ObjectsState.selectedObjects)
  ]).pipe(
    map(([objects, selectedObjects]) => 
      // Use .map and spread the obj into a new object, adding the isChecked property in the process
      objects.map(obj => ({
        ...obj,
        isChecked: selectedObjects.some(({id}) => obj.id === id)
      }))
    )
  )
}
```

**Alternative 3: Precalculate the value in NGXS @Selector**

Another way to precalculate the value is using an NGXS @Selector, which also transfers the logic to your state, making it reusable across your application. Performance-wise this should be about the same as alternative 2.

*The state:*

```js
@Injectable()
@State<ObjectStateModel>({
  name: 'object'
})
export class ObjectState {
  // These 2 already seem to exist in your state
  @Selector() public static objects(state: ObjectStateModel) {}
  @Selector() public static selectedObjects(state: ObjectStateModel) {}
  // Or with "selectorOptions.injectContainerState = false"
  @Selector([ObjectState]) public static objects(state: ObjectStateModel) {}
  @Selector([ObjectState]) public static selectedObjects(state: ObjectStateModel) {}

  // The new selector that does the precalculation. Depending on if you have
  // "selectorOptions.injectContainerState" set to true or false, the first
  // parameter will always be the state or not. I'll add both here.

  // With "selectorOptions.injectContainerState = true" (default)
  @Selector([ObjectState.objects, ObjectState.selectedObjects])
  public static objectsWithIsCheckedProperty(state, objects, selectedObjects) {
    return objects.map(obj => ({
      ...obj,
      isChecked: selectedObjects.some(({id}) => obj.id === id)
    }))
  }

  // With "selectorOptions.injectContainerState = false" (recommended)
  @Selector([ObjectState.objects, ObjectState.selectedObjects])
  // Notice that "state" is not provided by default anymore
  public static objectsWithIsCheckedProperty(objects, selectedObjects) {
    return objects.map(obj => ({
      ...obj,
      isChecked: selectedObjects.some(({id}) => obj.id === id)
    }))
  } 
}
```

And in your Component:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.objectsWithIsCheckedProperty$ = this.store.select(ObjectState.objectsWithIsCheckedProperty);
}
```

Comment: "selectorOptions.injectContainerState = false": how would we implement selectors when we cannot use the state in these selectors? I dont quiet get this option

Comment: You can inject it, you just have to explicitly set it like this: `@Selector([ObjectState])`. The benefit is that you don't have to inject it if you don't need it, (e.g. in our example above), which leads to further performance improvements since a state change will not trigger the selector to recalculate (only changes to whatever you provide in the @Selector array). I'll edit the code above to reflect that :)